# Listen to ZeroMQ in aiohttp application process

Tags: python, zeromq, gunicorn, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I run `aiohttp` application with `Gunicorn` behind `nginx`.
In my application's initialization module I don't run the application using `web.run_app(app)` but just create an instance that will be imported by `Gunicorn` to run it in each worker `Gunicorn` creates.
So `Gunicorn` creates a few worker processes, event loops within them, and then [runs](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/v0.22.5/aiohttp/worker.py#L36) the application's request handler in those loops.

My `aiohttp` application has a collection of connected `WebSockets` (mobile application clients) that I want to notify on event occurred in any of application processes started by `Gunicorn`.
And I want to notify **all** `WebSockets` that are connected to **all application processes**.
Therefore I create some kind of upstream proxy using `ZeroMQ` and I want to subscribe to it using `zmq.SUB` socket from each application process.

...So basically I want to achieve something like this in each application worker:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

while True:
    event = socket.recv()
    for ws in app['websockets']:
        ws.send_bytes(event)
    # break before app shutdown. How?
```

How can I listen the `ZeroMQ` proxy within `aiohttp` application to forward messages to `WebSockets`?

Where can I put this code to run in background within event loop and how to run and shutdown it correctly within `aiohttp` application's life cycle?

---

**UPDATE**

I've already created an [issue](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/issues/1092) in aiohttp's GitHub repository describing the problem and proposing a possible solution. I'd highly appreciate an input here or there on matter of the problem described.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same (combine ZMQ and aiohttp), but how does your answer relate to the question? that is not about zmq, is it?

Comment: @Alex Exactly. The question was how to listen to ZeroMQ (or any other queue) in background from the same aiohttp process. At that point of time aiohttp didn't have on_startup signal handler. But now it has, so there's no problem to listen any number of queues in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the question and the discussion on this [issue](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/issues/1092) has led to the new functionality I've contributed to `aiohttp`, namely in version **1.0** we'll have an ability to register `on_startup` application signals using `Application.on_startup()` method.

[Documentation](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web.html#aiohttp-web-background-tasks).
[Working example on the master branch](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/77fa3b5b86c3774d586ece6d6a59dd6eb5c93d8d/examples/background_tasks.py).

```py3
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Example of aiohttp.web.Application.on_startup signal handler"""
import asyncio

import aioredis
from aiohttp.web import Application, WebSocketResponse, run_app

async def websocket_handler(request):
    ws = WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    request.app['websockets'].append(ws)
    try:
        async for msg in ws:
            print(msg)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    finally:
        request.app['websockets'].remove(ws)
    return ws


async def on_shutdown(app):
    for ws in app['websockets']:
        await ws.close(code=999, message='Server shutdown')


async def listen_to_redis(app):
    try:
        sub = await aioredis.create_redis(('localhost', 6379), loop=app.loop)
        ch, *_ = await sub.subscribe('news')
        async for msg in ch.iter(encoding='utf-8'):
            # Forward message to all connected websockets:
            for ws in app['websockets']:
                ws.send_str('{}: {}'.format(ch.name, msg))
            print("message in {}: {}".format(ch.name, msg))
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass
    finally:
        print('Cancel Redis listener: close connection...')
        await sub.unsubscribe(ch.name)
        await sub.quit()
        print('Redis connection closed.')


async def start_background_tasks(app):
    app['redis_listener'] = app.loop.create_task(listen_to_redis(app))


async def cleanup_background_tasks(app):
    print('cleanup background tasks...')
    app['redis_listener'].cancel()
    await app['redis_listener']


async def init(loop):
    app = Application(loop=loop)
    app['websockets'] = []
    app.router.add_get('/news', websocket_handler)
    app.on_startup.append(start_background_tasks)
    app.on_cleanup.append(cleanup_background_tasks)
    app.on_shutdown.append(on_shutdown)
    return app

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
run_app(app)
```